# curl in bash script adds ? at end of the file name

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, scripts, curl

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, and I have a bash script with a curl command, for example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
curl https://www.example.com/file.txt > ./file.txt
```

The file should be downloaded with the name `file.txt` but when I do ls I see:

```bsh
$ ls
file.txt?
```

Why does it do that and how to remove this `?` ?

Thanks

Comment: You're right. I used `dos2unix` to convert the file and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script has Windows line endings.

If you run your script using `./script.sh`, it should output:

```
bash: ./script.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

If you run `bash script.sh`, it will save the file with `?` at the end like you are reporting.

Change your editor to use Unix line endings or use `dos2unix script.sh` to convert to Unix line endings.